# How to tell ASP.NET application what Active Directory to use?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

IIS Configuration:

```
Anonymous Authentication    Enabled
ASP.NET Impersonation       Enabled
Windows Authentication      Enabled
*the rest is disabled
```

Web.Config:

```
<add name="ADConn" connectionString="LDAP://192.168.0.21" />
.
.
.
<authentication mode="Windows" />

<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
<identity impersonate="true"/>

<membership defaultProvider="ADMembership">
  <providers>
    <add name="ADMembership"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="ADConn"
         connectionUsername="dominic"
         attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
         connectionPassword="p@ssw0rd" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

And in my web application:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

I'm trying to convert my application from Form to Windows Authentication. With this configuration, the page prompts me with login dialog. When I use my AD account, I can't login, but when I use my local account, I can visit the page. Why? How would I tell my application to use a specific AD? Is my configuration correct?

Important notes:

- My IIS and AD are on different machines and they are not on the same domain.
- My IIS and client is on the same machine.
- My application works with Form Authentication using AD.
- IIS version: 6.1
- MVC version: 4
- AD OS: Windows 2008
- Client and IIS OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think is happening
When you try to open the application, the browser will send your current AD credentials (if IE is configured to do this automatically)
Since you are using asp.net impersonation, If the AD account doesn't have access to the application folder it will try to use the anonymous user account instead which also doesn't have access.
You might need to add security access to application folder for the anonymous user defined in IIS otherwise remove the anonymous access from IIS
you can check the following link for the setting permission guidelines
   [Guidelines for Resolving IIS Permissions Problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa954062.aspx)

Comment: I don't understand. I disabled impersonation and anonymous authentication but I still can't log in using my AD account.

Comment: How about my configurations in web.config? Should I add or remove something?

Comment: Try to add your username to in the security permission for the application folder

Comment: My IIS and AD are on different machines and they are not on the same domain.

Comment: I think Windows authentication is not for you then, otherwise how the IIS should get the user trying to open the application if it is not part of the the same domain
Remember that the browser don't send the username and password, it actually send a token can only be resolved by the AD and dosn;t make any sense outside the context of the domain

Comment: Then why does the browser asks for username and password if it won't be sent to the server?

Comment: do you mean I need to make my IIS machine a member of the domain? At least the IIS, not the client PC? Thanks!

Comment: exactly, you need to make the IIS machine as part of your domain, not the client

Comment: If the server can't find the user he will ask for username and password and will use AD to resolve them, but to do this the IIS and AD should be in the same domain

Comment: Its my first time dealing with AD. I was having a hard time and you just gave me the missing link! :D Now it's working. Thanks @Joseph!